# Navigation issues with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

My problem is as follows:

I have a simple navigation

```
<ul class="navigation">
                <li class="heading selected">Slider images</li>
                <li><a href="index.php?action=staticpages" title="">Static pages</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?action=accomodation" title="">Accomodation</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?action=general" title="">General</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?action=settings" title="">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?action=dologout" title="">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

and my "not finished" jQuery function:

```
$('.navigation li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.navigation li').removeClass('heading selected');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('heading selected');
});
```

The **li** element with class **"heading selected"** is the default/selected element.

What I want to achieve after clicking on the other **li** element:

```
            <li><a href="index.php?action=sliderimages" title="">Slider images</a></li>
            <li class="heading selected">Static pages</li>
```

in short, remove "**heading selected**" list class from the default one, assing this class to the newly clicked element, also, add anchor href to the default one, and remove anchor tag from the newly clicked element.

Thanks in advance guys! :)

Comment: `class="heading selected"` assigns *two* classes, not one. The class attribute contains a white-space separated list of class-names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this somewhat more simple to implement, I'd suggest you don't add/remove the `a` elements from the `li`, and simply use CSS to style the elements as 'default text', and JS to prevent the default behaviour.

You can use this as a guide:

```
$('.navigation li a').click(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is('.headingSelected')) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $(this)
                .closest('li')
                .siblings()
                .removeClass('headingSelected');
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('headingSelected');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YTAgs/).

Note that I've concatenated your 'heading selected' class names into one single, camel-cased, 'headingSelected', also, in the linked demo, I had to guess what the URL of the first link should be. So be aware of that if you should try a direct copy/paste.

---

**Edited** to address my misconception that this was used for intra-page navigation, or Ajax interaction.

The following seems to work, but will need to be included in all pages that require the functionality (Whether in-line in the `head` of the document or via a linked js file):

```
var currentURL = "http://www.yourwebsite.com/index.php?action=staticpages";
var page = currentURL.substring(currentURL.indexOf('=') + 1);

$('.navigation a').each(
    function(i){
        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','') == page) {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('headingSelected');
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YTAgs/7/).

If you should use the above, simply ensure that you remove the `headingSelected` class name from the `html`, and allow the script to assign the class when it runs.

More concisely, but otherwise exactly the same as the previously edited answer, you could use instead:

```
var currentURL = "http://www.yourwebsite.com/index.php?action=staticpages";
var page = currentURL.substring(currentURL.indexOf('=') + 1);

$('a[href$="' + page + '"]').closest('li').addClass('headingSelected');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YTAgs/8/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).
- [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
- [`attrubte$="value"` attribute-ends-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).

Comment: Thanks for this. Will use CSS to style anchor. All works fine now except the URLs. When I click on the other element, the style changes but not the URL. :S

Comment: That's because I've used `return false` in both the `if` **and** the `else`. To follow the URL you'll probably have to remove the `return false` from the `else` and handle the click event appropriately there. Assuming you're using Ajax you might need to use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

Comment: When you click a link is a new page loading? Because if so the above isn't much of a help, since that occurs in one page, which is unloaded when you follow the link to the new page...

Comment: When I remove the 'return false' from 'else', the page changes, but the style ('heading selected') returns to the default list item. In this example, when I click on **accomodation**, the URL changes correctly, but the style returns back to the first item **Slider images**

Comment: Yes; because you've loaded a new page...I'll see what I can do to help out with that.

Comment: No worries at all, I'm glad to have been of help! And, genuinely, thank you for the answer acceptance! =)

Comment: This solution works. Just had to change from "window.location" to "window.location.href". Many many thanks David :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a solution that will add/remove the a element from the li as David Thomas mentioned.

```
$('.navigation li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.navigation li').removeClass('heading selected');
    $('.navigation li').each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).children().size() == 0) {
            $(this).html("<a href='index.php?action=" + $(this).text().replace(' ', '').toLowerCase() + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</a>")
        }
    });
    $(this).parent().html($(this).text());
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('heading selected');
});
```